# Varnish Conflicts With Let's Encrypt Certificate Renewal

Tags: apache, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a woocommerce site that runs on Ubuntu.  I'm unable to renew the let's encrypt certificate because port 80 is occupied by varnish, instead of Apache 2 server.  Any attempt to put Apache server back listening on port 80 results in not being able to start the apache server.  When I try to delete and purge varnish, it says it can't be found on the system, which isn't true.  How can I delete Varnish 6 and restore Apache 2 server to listen to port 80 again?

My current ubuntu system is version 19.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You really don't want to remove Varnish and have Apache take port 80, because you would nog longer be protected by Varnish.

What you're really looking for, is a way for Varnish to identify Letsencrypt revalidation challenges, and pass them on to Apache.

### VCL snippet to bypass Varnish for Letsencrypt revalidation challenges

Based on https://docs.varnish-software.com/tutorials/hitch-letsencrypt/, you can add the follow snippets to your VCL to make sure LetsEncrypt validation bypasses Varnish:

```
backend certbot {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/") {
        set req.backend_hint = certbot;
        return(pipe);
    }
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    if (req.backend_hint == certbot) {
        set req.http.Connection = "close";
        return(pipe);
    }
}
```

This snippet assumes that you're using the [HTTP-01 challenge type](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#http-01-challenge) and also assumes you're Apache is running on port `8080`.

### What about your TLS proxy?

Although Apache will be in charge of serving the Letsencrypt HTTP challenge, you'll probably use another piece of software to terminate TLS before sending it to Varnish.

What TLS proxy are you using? Do you have the logic in place to transport the new certificate to its proper location?

See https://docs.varnish-software.com/tutorials/hitch-letsencrypt/ for inspiration.